# How to block all IP adresses from secureserver.net using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This usually would work using allow,deny:

order allow,deny
deny from secureserver.net
allow from all

But for this specific domain the logs show that it is still allowing access, for example:
ip-50-63-174-95.ip.secureserver.net gets an 200 ok response to requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Limit GET POST>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from .secureserver.edu
</Limit>
```

Comment: Would that substitute my order allow,deny for all the other domains that are blocked correctly? It seems vulnerable: http://blog.ncircle.com/t5/VERT-Security-Research-Blog/Turn-That-S-T-Off-Apache-htaccess-Limit-Tag/ba-p/4942